# Using a constructor on a JavaScript static instance

Tags: javascript, object, static, instance, private

I'm writing a JavaScript library in which I want some methods and properties public and other private. The following seems a great way of doing this whilst wrapping everything up into a single object.

```
(function (window) {
   var Thing = function() {
      // private var
      var variable = "value";

      return {
         // public method
         method:function() {
            alert(variable);
         }
      }
   }();

   window.Thing = Thing;

})(window);

Thing.method();
```

Which is great. (Mostly grabbed from [here](http://blogger.xs4all.nl/peterned/archive/2006/08/15/114545.aspx)).

However, I'd still like to be able to use the constructor of `Thing` to pass in some arguments.

Is there anyway I can provide a constructor in the return statement, or use prototype to override the constructor? So I can call:

```
Thing(stuff);
```

Right now, if I try that it causes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'Thing' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

Which makes sense as it's not returning itself, but ideally it'd be possible to call a constructor.

OR, is this just baaaad and I should steer clear of some or all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you are asking, do something like this:

```
(function (window) {
   var thingMaker= function(stuff) {
      // private var
      var variable = "value";

      return {
         // public method
         method:function() {
            alert(variable);
         }
         alertStuff:function() {
            alert(stuff);
         }
      }
   };

   window.thingMaker= thingMaker;

})(window);

var myThing = window.thingMaker(stuff);
myThing.alertStuff()
```

More information can be found by searching the googlenets for Douglas Crockford.  Some great and very informative videos by him are available on [yui theater](http://yuilibrary.com/theater/).  But I would have to ask, why create another framework when there are already so many great ones out there (jquery,prototype,yui,dojo to name a few)

Comment: This is the closest answer to what I was hoping for, thanks. However I still really wanted to be able to access methods statically, rather than assigning the object to a variable. In the end I decided against the approach in the question, and instead keep privates inside the anonymous function Thing is defined within rather than wrapped in the object Thing.

Answer (score 0):

`Thing` is already created, so you are always going to be too late to call a 'constructor'.

You could pass variables in like this:

```
(function (window, var1, var2) {
  var Thing = function() {
  // private var
  var variable = "value";

  return {
     // public method
     method:function() {
        alert(variable);
     }
  }
}();
window.Thing = Thing;
})(window, var1, var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Thing` is an `Object` with one method called `method`:

```
  {
     // public method
     method:function() {
        alert(variable);
     }
  }

Thing.method(); // alerts "value"
```

You could return instead:

```
function () {
    alert(arguments)
}
```

Then

```
Thing(6,5,4); // alerts 6,5,4
```